# Connect AnyLogic to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, anylogic

the new build-in database in AnyLogic 7.3 allows to connect to a SQL Server database. I am struggling to connect it to a *local* database that I set up using SQL Management Studio (using SQL Server 2008 R2).

A few more facts to clarify:

- My dbase is called "myDBase" and has a db_owner called "myNewLogin".
- I log into SQL Management Studio using "Server type" = Database engine. The Server name is "NAMEOFMYMACHINE\SQLEXPRESS". I set "Authentication" to Windows authentication
- my login "myNewLogin" is set to use "SQL Server authentication" in its properties. It uses "myPassword" as a password (but doesn't enforce it)
- I set up the AnyLogic import wizard as below:
  [image: AnyLogic SQL wizard]

I have tried to use different inputs (such as "sa" for the Login,...) but in any combination, I always get the error

> "Login failed for user ..."

I have also turned off my Windows firewall to allow port 1433 communication, but the result is the same.

Have you been able to load from a local SQL Server database? How did you set it up, which versions did you use... The more specific your reply, the better.

thx a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again for your help.

I fixed the problem by installing SQL Server 2014 (was 2008) and logging in using "Mixed Method" with a "sa" account.

Comment: Thanks for returning with your solution. The issue was not the version, the issue appears to be that your tool (AnyLogic) only supports SQL Authentication and not Windows authentication. From your description, you had not set up a SQL User only a windows user.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried host: localhost\sqlexpress ?

Comment: thx, this shows a different error: "Unknown server host name 'localhost\sqlexpress"... Any chance this might be down to the SQL Server version?

Comment: Have you tried (local)\SQLExpress? You could also try "NAMEOFMYMACHINE\SQLEXPRESS" as the Hostname